# Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 with Toast.makeText

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

My app is getting crashed when i click on RecyclerView item, The Error is occurring Because of `Toast.make()`, when i comment or remove the `Toast` in `check(positon:Int)` function then it doesn't crash. It is only crashing while `Toast` is there. I search a lot for a fix but i couldn't find one, please help to fix this error

```
fun check(position: Int)
{
   Log.i("Check", position.toString())
   //if i remove the comment the app will crash
   //Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

> Error:

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebase_image_upload, PID: 27287
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:287)
        at com.example.firebase_image_upload.ImagesActivity$check$1.run(ImagesActivity.kt:63)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Using `Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` you are trying to use [the method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, 
                int resId, 
                int duration)
```

where the resId represents **the resource id** of the string resource to use (as `R.string.xxxx)`.

Use **`position.toString()`** to convert the int into a String:

```
Toast.makeText(this, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(ProjectActivity.this,  "Your message here",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The second parameter is `String` but you are using `Int` here, convert your `Int` to `String` will make work done
ex:

```
`Toast.makeText(this, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`



Toast.makeText(this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```